# How to have a form load to a certain record from criteria on a Navigation Form in Ms Access

Tags: ms-access, navigation

I have a NavForm in MS Access 2010.  It's source is the main table in the DB.  It's header contains the record ID 'LotNumber'.

The nav bar has 3 buttons, each representing a separate form; Customer Info, House Info, Decor Info.

I would like the form to load to the matching record that the main Nav form is on.  For example, Nav form is on LotNumber 25, and when you click the Decor Info button, the form opens to LotNumber 25.

Basically, it's like a Master / Child relationship used in subforms, but I'm using a Nav Form because I like the layout and "web site" feel to it.

Comment: So you have three tabs on your form, each with a 'subform' for specific information? You should use the "LinkMaster" and "LinkChild" properties on the subform and set the "LinkMaster" value to 'LotNumber' and the "LinkChild" to the matching field in the subform.

Comment: There are no master child links within a navigation form. So that can't work. I require the form loaded by the navigation routine to load to a certain record using criteria on the Navigation form

Comment: Another way to look at it would be for the form to execute a search on the Lot number field using the the criteria in the lot number field on the Navigation form.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following to work with a Nav form using three tabs. I created the ComboBox named 'LotNumber' in the header of the Nav form.  Then I added the following code to the Form_Open event for each of the three tab forms. You can do away with the 'On Error Resume Next' line, but since I also use my forms stand-alone, there would be no Parent with a LotNumber, thus this avoids an error.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim rs As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    If Me.Parent.Name <> "XXXXX" Then
        Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
        rs.FindFirst "[ID] = " & Me.Parent.[LotNumber]
        Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Wayne,  Thanks for the info. Need a little more guidance.  First, the Me.Parent.Name portion, do I need to replace "name" with the Parent form name?  In this case, the form containing the Navigation menu is called "Nav".

Comment: Second, what does the "XXXX" represent?

Comment: I can't put any formatting in my comments for some reason.  I tried your code using my form names in stead of "Name" and nothing happened.  No error.

Comment: Paste the code exactly as is into your subform (tab) code, then replace ONLY [ID] with the name of the field in your subform you want to search for the value in comboBox 'LotNumber' on the main form. In your case 'Parent.Name' will = 'NAV'. I should have deleted the lines 'On Error', and the 'If = XXXX' and 'End If', but expected more questions & testing. Since I can open any of my subforms by themselves (standalone), the 'If XXX...' will skip this code that is only desired to be used by a Nav form.

Comment: Something isn't right.  I put the code in On Open procedure in the subform , and still nothing.  Let me give you specifics again and maybe I crossed something

Comment: Main form name:  Nav ; Suform Name:  Customer  Both forms have Lot_Number fields that need to match up.  So, when you click on the navigation button that calls up the Customer subform, it should open up to the corresponding lot_number.

Comment: Please open the 'Customer' form in design view, for the Form object look at the 'On Open' event and make sure there is a link to your code. Sometimes if you paste code, the event is not automatically linked. Also, make sure that the FindFirst field name is the name of the field in your Customer recordset and not the control name. Finally, I see you just inserted an "_" in Lot_Number... which is correct - that should be the name of the combo box control.